# java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: factory with hibernate upgrade

Tags: hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

I have upgraded hibernate from `5.1.17` to `5.4.11` and along with this I also upgraded hibernate search and lucene as well. Below are the details

```
Hibernate: 5.1.17 to 5.4.11
Hibernate-search-orm: 5.5.2 to 5.11.5
Lucene:  5.3.1 to 5.5.5
```

I am getting `java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: factory` error at `AbstractSessionImpl.class.getDeclaredField("factory");`

What would be reason for this?
What are the suggested/compatible of `Hibernate-search-orm` and `Lucene` for `hibernate 5.4.11`??

EDIT: This is where it is causing issue and this code exists from long time.
I got this issue while running test cases and it is pointing to below method in our code.

```
 private Set<String> getAllQueryNames() {
        Set<String> queryNames = Sets.newHashSet();
        try {
            Field factoryField = AbstractSessionImpl.class.getDeclaredField("factory");
            factoryField.setAccessible(true);
            SessionFactoryImpl factory = (SessionFactoryImpl) factoryField.get(getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession());
            Field namedQueriesField = SessionFactoryImpl.class.getDeclaredField("namedQueryRepository");
            namedQueriesField.setAccessible(true);
            NamedQueryRepository namedQueryRepository = (NamedQueryRepository) namedQueriesField.get(factory);

            Field namedQueryDefinitionMapField = NamedQueryRepository.class.getDeclaredField("namedQueryDefinitionMap");
            namedQueryDefinitionMapField.setAccessible(true);
            Map namedQueryDefinitionMap = (Map) namedQueryDefinitionMapField.get(namedQueryRepository);


            queryNames.addAll(namedQueryDefinitionMap.keySet());

        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        return queryNames;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What would be reason for this

Assuming the code that failed is yours, it is intrinsically unsafe:

- It relies on an *internal*, non-API class: `AbstractSessionImpl`. Those classes are not meant to be accessed by users.
- It uses reflection to access one of its *private* fields: `factory`. Those fields are not meant to be accessed by users.

In short, the code that fails is probaly just a hack, and that hack no longer works in recent versions of Hibernate ORM/Search.

You didn't provide the full stack trace, so I don't know where the code is.
If the code is yours, you should find a new hack. I can't help without knowing what the code is supposed to do.
If the code is in Hibernate ORM or Search, please give the full stack trace.

> What are the suggested/compatible of Hibernate-search-orm and Lucene for hibernate 5.4.11??

The versions you're using are fine. If you want to be sure, check out [the compatibility matrix](https://hibernate.org/search/releases/#compatibility-matrix). The problem lies in the hack, as explained above.

EDIT: So, it's a hack. You should use SPIs instead, as much as you can. Instead of this:

```
            Field factoryField = AbstractSessionImpl.class.getDeclaredField("factory");
            factoryField.setAccessible(true);
            SessionFactoryImpl factory = (SessionFactoryImpl) factoryField.get(getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession());
            Field namedQueriesField = SessionFactoryImpl.class.getDeclaredField("namedQueryRepository");
            namedQueriesField.setAccessible(true);
            NamedQueryRepository namedQueryRepository = (NamedQueryRepository) namedQueriesField.get(factory);

            Field namedQueryDefinitionMapField = NamedQueryRepository.class.getDeclaredField("namedQueryDefinitionMap");
            namedQueryDefinitionMapField.setAccessible(true);
            Map namedQueryDefinitionMap = (Map) namedQueryDefinitionMapField.get(namedQueryRepository);
```

Do this:

```
            NamedQueryRepository namedQueryRepository = getSessionFactory().unwrap(SessionFactoryImplementor.class)
                        .getNamedQueryRepository()

            Field namedQueryDefinitionMapField = NamedQueryRepository.class.getDeclaredField("namedQueryDefinitionMap");
            namedQueryDefinitionMapField.setAccessible(true);
            Map namedQueryDefinitionMap = (Map) namedQueryDefinitionMapField.get(namedQueryRepository);
```

The second part is still a hack, is still fragile, and will still potentially break in next versions of Hibernate ORM. But at least it should work for now.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am also following same matrix for compatibility check. Thanks for confirming.  I added details in my question. Please check my EDIT and let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: I can see that `AbstractSessionImpl` is modified and a new class `AbstractSharedSessionContract` is introduced as its parent. I think either I should change the method implementation or I should use this new class instead.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. Will try and let you know.